# Get the input with xPath from a Jquery data-bvalidator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xpath

I'm trying to get the values of an input field using xPath to validade that the site is working as expected.

But some of the input tags are using jquery data-bvalidator and i cannot access the text/value on them.

You have an example page here:
[bvalidator usage](http://bojanmauser.from.hr/bvalidator/#allvalidators)

If you try to put some text, for example "Alfa" on the first input box and try to access it, in debug mode, using:

```
$x('//*[@id="form1"]/div/div[1]/p[1]/input')
```

you will just get the element `<input type="text" data-bvalidator="alpha,minlength[10],required">`and not the "Alfa" value.

how can i get around this?

PS: This only works in chrome.

Comment: You can get the value with  `$x('//*[@id="form1"]/div/div[1]/p[1]/input')[0].value`. Getting the value with xpath only is not possible.

Comment: @hr_117 Thanks for that, that solves one issue :) The other one is that we are using selinium to automate web site tests, and the selinium is working with xPath and like this we will be screwed :/

Comment: Hm / do not think so. With seinium you can use `ele.GetAttribute("value")` where `ele` is the first element from the xpaht search. But problem here is that you left out to many details in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the **value property** with xpath is not possible.
Wiht xpaht you can get the value attribute value - if there is one. But this would never refelect the changes of the input value (property).

```
 $x('//*[@id="form1"]/div/div[1]/p[1]/input/@value')
```

To get the property `value` you can use  (in Chrome Debugger):

```
  $x('//*[@id="form1"]/div/div[1]/p[1]/input')[0].value
```

Update due to the mentioned of selenium in comment:

With selenium you can use `ele.getAttribute("value")` where ele is the first element from the xpaht search result. 
Or something like:

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(
       '//*[@id="form1"]/div/div[1]/p[1]/input')).getAttribute(‌​"value");
```